# Is it possible to use InStr() combined with Application.Vlookup()?

Tags: excel, vba, formula, vlookup

I currently have a With statement that will compare the value of a cell to a range of cells and `InStr()` returns true then mark `cell.Value` as "`Yes"` and if not then `"No"`.

Here is the scenario. Say I am checking the value of `A2` and this is `111`. I am comparing `111` to a range of other cells and the field that should match is `111, 222, 333` as it contains `111` in it. My first set of code below works for this but is slow. I was hoping for a faster way and I think I can do this with a formula but using `True` instead of `False` in the vlookup is not working as I thought it would.

Here is the code:

```
With inv_twcg_ws
    For Each cell In .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        For Each cellx In report_rng
            If InStr(cellx.Value, cell.Value) Then
                cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = "Yes"
                Exit For
            End If
                cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = "No"
        Next cellx
    Next cell
End With
```

The problem is it is kinda slow. My application takes about 5 min to run. I was hoping to combine `InStr()` with `Application.Vlookup()` somehow to try and speed up the formula. Is this possible?

Here is my current Vlookup but using `True` does not seam to be working for my needs...

```
With inv_twcg_ws
    For Each cell In .Range("G2:G" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(CStr(cell.Value), report_rng, 1, True), "No")
    Next cell
End With
```

Comment: Better of reading into arrays and working with arrays then writing back to sheet.

Comment: @QHarr I am good with list/Arrays in Python but I have not worked at all with Arrays in VBA. I would need to do some research on Arrays at this point.

Comment: @QHarr shouldn't `True` in the Vlookup return a match if the value is in the cell? Or am I wrong in my understanding of what the `True/False` argument is for?

Comment: True is relative as in it finds where the cell fits in order and the lookup list must be sorted ascending.

Comment: @ScottCraner Oh I see. I will have to read up on it some more then. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use variant arrays:

```
Dim report_ws As Worksheet
Set report_ws = report_wb.Worksheets(1)

Dim report_rng As Variant
report_rng = report_ws.Range("B2:B" & last_row)

Dim inv_twcg_ws As Worksheet
Set inv_twcg_ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' change to your sheet




With inv_twcg_ws
    Dim lkup_rng As Variant
    lkup_rng = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value

    Dim otpt As Variant
    ReDim otpt(1 To UBound(lkup_rng, 1), 1 To 1) As Variant

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(lkup_rng, 1) To UBound(lkup_rng, 1)
        otpt(i,1) = "No"
        Dim j As Long
        For j = LBound(report_rng, 1) To UBound(report_rng, 1)
            If InStr(report_rng(j, 1), lkup_rng(i, 1)) Then
                otpt(i,1) = "Yes"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    .Range("G2").Resize(UBound(otpt, 1)).Value = otpt
End With
```

Comment: Thanks Scott I will test this soon.

Comment: Very nice and speedy.

Comment: @QHarr I had actually started this with the OP's last question, but stopped when my comments fixed that specific issue.

Comment: @Scott. That worked 100 times faster! I need to really read up on this method. It will help a massive amount in my other projects.

Comment: @Mike-SMT worksheet reads & writes are pretty much the slowest thing you can do in Excel+VBA - learn to love in-memory arrays, they'll love you back!

Comment: I noticed that if I change `.Range("G2").Resize(UBound(otpt, 1)).Value = otpt` to `.Range("G2:G" & UBound(otpt, 1)).Value = otpt` I get the same results. Is ther a benefit or reason for using `Resize()`?

Comment: @Mike-SMT yes there is.  You are slicing off the last value.  If the array which starts at one has 100 records, mine make the range `G2:G101` while yours will make it `G2:G100` missing the last item in the array.

Comment: Ok so in that case could i not just do `.Range("G2:G" & UBound(otpt, 1) + 1).Value = otpt`? I am just trying to make sure that there is not some major reason to use `Resize` It seams like it is redundant. Also thanks for the quick reply. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Mike-SMT yes you can do that, but what if you wanted to start in row 115, then you would need to do that math.  That is why I prefer Resize.  I just need to define the upper left cell then not worry about anything else.  You can do it that way.  Resize will be a fraction of a second faster as vba does not need to parse a string, but yours will work.

Comment: That is good to know. The faster the better really. It is a big project. I will Keep that in mind.

Comment: @Mike-SMT then think if your upper left cell is dynamic, as in you are looping and want to start in the first row that is blank.  The string would get quite long as you add the logic to find what needs to be subtracted.

Comment: I wonder why `.Range()` is losing the last value in the array? Why would Range count things differently than Resize?

Comment: @Mike-SMT it is the math, lets take it to the extreme.  Say the size of the array is 100.  Our upper left corner where we want to place the values is G99.  With mine the range in which we place the values will be G99:G198 while yours will be G99:G100.  Rember that when assigning the values to an array it is independent of source value rows.  It will start at item 1 in the array.  So `arr=Range("G100:G199").value` will fill an array with a Lbound of 1 and a UBound of 100.

Comment: Ohhhhh. Let me see if I understand this. Basically say I have `Range("G20:G40")` and I have created an array from that range. If I try to do `.Range("G20:G" & UBound(otpt, 1) ).Value = otpt` Then My actual range will end up being `"G20:G21"`  Because `UBond(otpt, 1)` would return the last index of the list as 21. But `Resize()` will add that 21 to whatever the starting number is for the range instead making my range accurate to `G40`?

Comment: @Mike-SMT yup, that is why I use Resize, no thinking.

Comment: It makes sense now. Thank you. Last question. Going of the logic in my last commend would `Resize()` give me `G20:G40` or `G20:G41`? If feel like it should be 41 due to the number resizing by 21. Unless it is taking 21 and starting at G20 as number 1 out of 21.

Comment: No, `Range("A1").Resize(1,1)` would return a range of only A1.  It is different than Offset.  So `Range("G20").Resize(21)` would return a range 21 cells which is `G20:G40`

Comment: Great. I understand perfectly now. Very helpful. I figured out how all the array stuff was working I was just confused on that `Resize()` method. I get it now you have been very helpful :D